# Still can't select created element from javascript

Tags: javascript

I successfully created 5 divs to my page

```js
for (var i=0; i<5; i+=1 ) {
  //getANewNumber(10); // Don't mind this line
  newBox = document.createElement('div');
  newBox.innerHTML = newBox.innerHTML + '1';
  document.body.appendChild(newBox);
}

var nDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div').innerHTML;
console.log(nDiv);
```

But I can not select the created divs. When I console.log, it returns undefined.

Comment: The `getElementsByTagName()` function will return multiple elements. If you want to select individual elements, then you might consider setting an `id` attribute to select them independently through `getElementById()`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to be specifically mention which div's innerHTML you need like this.

```
var nDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML;//here getting first div's innerHTML
console.log(nDiv);
```